# SearchView icon shows twice

Tags: java, android, toolbar, searchview

I've implemented SearchView inside my toolbar, following Android's official instructions.

SearchView works well itself, but when I tap the search icon, it is shifted to the left instead of showing the Search Hint and Close button, although if I click this "second Search" icon, finally I get the typical search view.

Here is my xml of the toolbar:

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_view"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

And my onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
```

And my manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/addWordLabel_Act"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
```

Finally, here you have some screenshots of the problem:
[SearchView before tapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zihl.png)

[SearchView after first tap, Here's the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go2EK.png)

[SearchView after second tap, "the normal SearchView"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGoxE.png)

And that's all.

Note: I haven't implemented an Activity/Fragment to handle the Search yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. It was easy, but I've spent two days trying to figure it out.

Just, for compatibility issues, use

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

instead of `app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"`

and, of course, change

```
SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
       SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
```

by

```
SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView =
                (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
```

Comment: can't use that with androidx

Answer (score 4):

## Androidx solution

Adding this answer because my reputation wasn't enough to reply to Wesley Franks

#### Layout

```
app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
```

#### Activity (Kotlin)

```
menu?.findItem(R.id.search)?.actionView as? androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
```

#### Activity (Java)

```java
(androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
```

Comment: works with androidx, this must be used for the apps being created with androidx.

Answer (score 0):

**This is best answer for this issue**

```java
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_search);
        final androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView searchView = (androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                searchView.setQuery("", false);
                searchView.setIconified(true);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                  //Do your stuff
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of above solution works for you as in my case:
Just set background color to the SearchView. 
And you will only see 1 magnifying glass icon.

Answer (score 0):

Before Calling the Menu Item Clear the Menu First.

```
 menu.clear();
```

Full Code

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.appSearchBar).getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search...");
    searchView.setIconified(false);
```

onCreateOptionsMenu is use because i call it in Fragment.